# trivial S^1 bundle cann't admit sasakian structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

trivial S^1 bundle over compact even dim manifolds (not necessary Kahler)
cann't admit sasakian structure. Is it true? Why

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/faq

Answer (score 1):

It can't admit a Sasakian structure with the Reeb vector field $\xi$ tangent to the fibers.  The contact form $\eta$ defines a connection on the bundle with $d\eta$ positive orthogonal to the fibers.  This is impossible on a trivial bundle.